# Convert each row of a dataframe column containing sets into a column containing lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
cpc         count   gau
F21S41/32   5       {2875}
F21S41/147  21      {2875}
F21S41/692  20      {2875}
B60Q1/0041  15      {2683, 2875, 2844}
F21S43/40   15      {2875}
F21S41/435  14      {2875}
```

For each row, I want to multiply the count by the gau to produce a new column called `w_gau`.

Ultimatly, I want df1 to look like this:

```
cpc         count   gau                 w_gau
F21S41/32   5      {2875}               ['2875', '2875', '2875', '2875', '2875'] 
F21S41/147  3      {2875}               ['2875', '2875', '2875']
F21S41/692  2      {2875}               ['2875', '2875']
B60Q1/0041  2      {2683, 2875, 2844}   ['2683', '2875', '2844', '2683', '2875', '2844', '2683', '2875', '2844']
F21S43/40   3      {2875}               ['2875', '2875', '2875']
F21S41/435  4      {2875}               ['2875', '2875', '2875', '2875']
```

I already have code to flatten the lists into a single list and count the occurrences of each string.

My question is how do I convert `gau` in df1 to a list of lists that I can multiply by an integer?

I've tried:

```
In [16]: df1.gau.tolist()
```

But that converts everything in the column to a single list. I need each row to contain a list with each string or int being a string in the list.

EDIT: the gau is a string, not an int

```
df1.dtypes
Out[24]: 
cpc      object
count     int64
gau      object
w_gau    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing goofy things like this, you should stop and rethink your approach.

That said, you asked for the scissors and here they are

```
df['gau'].apply(list) * df['count']
```

As a new column

```
df.assign(w_gau=df['gau'].apply(list) * df['count'])
```

---

If your `gau` column are strings, run this to turn them to sets.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['gau'] = df['gau'].apply(literal_eval)
```

Then run the other code.

Comment: true I need a better way to weight, but this is how i am doing it for the moment.  That said, when i tried you solution, I do not get the answer I want.

['{', '2', '6', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '7', '5', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '4', '4', '}', '{', '2', '6', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '7', '5', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '4', '4', '}', '{', '2', '6', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '7', '5', ',', ' ', '2', '8', '4', '4', '}', '{', '2', '6', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '2', '8',..., '}']

Comment: That must mean your items are strings.  See my update.  It should clear it up.

Comment: Works, great. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df['New']=[list(x)*y for x, y in zip(df['gau'],df['Count'])]
df
Out[628]: 
   Count        gau                 New
0      1        {1}                 [1]
1      2  {1, 2, 3}  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Count':[1,2],'gau':[{1},{1,2,3}]})
```

Comment: I neglected to mention that the type of gau is string not int. I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: @Britt it will be the same thing :-)

Comment: this actually does not work. The first row of df5.New looks like this:

['{', '2', '8', '7', '5', '}', '{', '2', '8', '7', '5', '}',...', '}']

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply a list by an integer, you reproduce it. Therefore you can find your way here by transforming elements in `gau` into list:

```
df['w_gau'] = df['count']*df.gau.apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

Note that storing lists into a pandas dataframe is rarely a good idea though, you might want to consider doing otherwise.

EDIT:

When you have an ill-formated series you can use the `literal_eval` function in `ast`library. Not that it is time and energy consuming though, so try as much as possible to prevent these situations.

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['gau'] = df['gau'].apply(literal_eval)
df['w_gau'] = df['count']*df.gau.apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

Comment: gau contains strings not, int so this does not work. I edited the questions to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer by adding a line that helps you transform the values in `gau` column beforehand.